# An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context:ngx-barcode scanner

Tags: angular, typescript

Im trying to use `ngx-barcode-scanner` in my angular application but I get the error `An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context`

code
app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ZXingScannerModule } from '@zxing/ngx-scanner';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ZXingScannerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'angular-tour-of-heroes';
}
```

app.component.html

```
<section class="results" *ngIf="qrResultString">
  <div>
    <small>Result</small>
    <strong>{{ qrResultString }}</strong>
  </div>
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="clearResult()">&times;</button>
</section>
```

the error log is

```
12     get isTorchAvailable(): Observable<boolean>;
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:104:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

104     get codeReader(): BrowserMultiFormatContinuousReader;
            ~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:108:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

108     set device(device: MediaDeviceInfo | null);
            ~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:116:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

116     get device(): MediaDeviceInfo | null;
            ~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:120:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

120     get formats(): BarcodeFormat[];
            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:126:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

126     set formats(input: BarcodeFormat[]);
            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:130:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

130     get hints(): Map<DecodeHintType, any>;
            ~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:134:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

134     set hints(hints: Map<DecodeHintType, any>);
            ~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:138:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

138     set isAutostarting(state: boolean | null);
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:142:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

142     get isAutostarting(): boolean | null;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:146:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

146     set torch(on: boolean);
            ~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:150:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

150     set enable(enabled: boolean);
            ~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:154:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

154     get enabled(): boolean;
            ~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:158:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

158     get tryHarder(): boolean;
            ~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/@zxing/ngx-scanner/lib/zxing-scanner.component.d.ts:162:9 - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.

162     set tryHarder(enable: boolean);
            ~~~~~~~~~
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Where is your `<zxing-scanner></zxing-scanner>` and how the full html looks like?

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti <zxing-scanner> is a plugin I installed from npm repo

Comment: Yes, that' true, how are you using zxing-scanner in the html and ts file? Can you post that code

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/zxing-js/ngx-scanner/issues/349#issuecomment-714524513), you have probably old version of Angular (<=8). You must upgrade Angular to a higher version.